# testthat can't find function in namespace

Tags: r, testthat

I have a test suite for an R package and am pretty sure it used to work, but now it doesn't.

The problem appears to be that the test functions can't find functions beginning with . that are in the package namespace.

An [example test is here](https://github.com/harrysouthworth/texmex/blob/master/tests/testthat/test.closures.R). The test function can't see .make.mvn.prior. even though it is [defined here](https://github.com/harrysouthworth/texmex/blob/master/R/efficient.closures.R).

A workaround is to use texmex:::.make.mvn.prior but I believe the use of ::: is frowned upon.

I'd be grateful of any insights.

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Searching for . and ::: isn't very productive.

Comment: "but I believe the use of ::: is frowned upon" Why should that be frowned upon if you use it for your own package in your own tests?

Comment: From Writing R Extensions: "Using foo:::f instead of foo::f allows access to unexported objects. This is generally not recommended...". Although R CMD check doesn't pick up on it in the test suite, assuming a future version won't seems unsafe. (The answer to your question, though, is "I don't know.")

Comment: The quote continues: "...as the semantics of unexported objects may be changed by the package author in routine maintenance." You are the package author and presumably you know if you change the semantics.

Comment: Ok, but the help file for test_package includes "Test are run in an environment that inherits from the package's namespace environment, so that tests can access non-exported functions and variables"